# Não consigo fazer uma função que retorna um Semestre de uma Data no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, stored-procedures

estou tentando fazer um conversão que retorna um semestre de uma data, mas apareceu esse erro aqui

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION semestre ( data timestamp )
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF data <= 6
        THEN return 1;
    ELSE
        return 2;
    END IF;
RETURN -1;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT semestre(timestamp '16/06/2017');
```

Mensagem de erro:

> ```
> ERRO:operador não existe: timestamp without time zone <= integer
> LINE 1: SELECT   $1  <= 6
>                      ^
> HINT:  Nenhum operador corresponde com o nome e o(s) tipo(s) de argumento(s) informados. Você precisa adicionar conversões de tipo explícitas.
> QUERY:  SELECT   $1  <= 6
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "semestre" line 2 at IF
> ```

o que poderia ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando comparar um timestamp com um inteiro, você tem que comparar apenas o mês.

faça assim:

```
 if date_part('month',data ) <=6
```

Ficaria assim a função:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION semestre ( data timestamp )
RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF date_part('month',data ) <=6
        THEN return 1;
    ELSE
        return 2;
    END IF;
RETURN -1;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```